# What are, and what has been learned from making plasma crystals in space? Is a tl;dr-like answer possible?

Tags: microgravity, russia, esa, experiment, plasma

The two articles below describe a set of plasma crystal experiments scheduled for 2019 aboard the ISS in cooperation with German and Russian scientists on the ground. These were not the first but might be the latest and definitely build directly upon [previous experiments](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn3704-space-station-unlocks-new-world-of-crystals/).

**Question:** In a nutshell, what are plasma crystals, what has been learned from making in space and why do they benefit from microgravity? Is a tl;dr-like answer possible for all of this so as to keep it on-topic here?

---

- DLR: [Plas­ma crys­tal re­search on the ISS](https://www.dlr.de/content/en/articles/news/2019/04/20191108_plasma-crystal-research-on-the-iss.html) (several interesting photos!)
- Parabolic Arc: [Plasma Crystal Research Conducted on the ISS](http://www.parabolicarc.com/2019/11/13/plasma-crystal-research-conducted-on-the-iss/)

---

[image: Cos­mo­naut Alexan­der Skvor­zow dur­ing the PK-4 ex­per­i­ments Image 1/5, Credit: ESA/ROSKOSMOS]

> Cos­mo­naut Alexan­der Skvor­zow dur­ing the PK-4 ex­per­i­ments Image 1/5, Credit: ESA/ROSKOSMOS

From [here](https://www.dlr.de/content/en/articles/news/2019/04/20191108_plasma-crystal-research-on-the-iss.html)

> The scientists are following the experiments with interest from the [CADMOS](https://cadmos.cnes.fr/en/cadmos-0) control centre in Toulouse, France. The cosmonaut's most important task is to start the measurements at the correct moment, by sending the microparticles through the ionised gas and capturing the movements of the 'complex plasmas' on the monitor. Skvortsov already has a certain amount of practical experience, as he is currently completing his third long-term stay on board the ISS. During his first mission, in 2010, he carried out plasma crystal experiments with the predecessor laboratory, PK-3 Plus, as part of a German-Russian collaboration. The current [PK-4](https://www.dlr.de/content/en/articles/missions-projects/horizons/experimente-horizons-pk4.html) laboratory has been installed in the European Columbus module on the ISS and, as a multipurpose multi-user facility, offers a wide range of possibilities for plasma research under microgravity conditions.

> The PK-4 plasma crystal laboratory is a European-Russian collaboration between the European Space Agency (ESA) and the Russian space agency, Roskos­mos (en­glisch), with scientific leadership from the [DLR Re­search Group Com­plex Plas­mas](http://complex-plasmas.dlr.de/) at the DLR Institute of Materials Physics in Space (formerly at the Max Planck Institute for Extraterrestrial Physics, MPE) and the Russian Academy of Sciences Joint Institute for High Temperatures ([JIHT](http://jiht.ru/en/about/we.php)). The experimental hardware was developed in-house by the group during their time at [MPE](http://www.mpe.mpg.de/2169/en/index), and by [OHB System AG](https://www.ohb-system.de/main-company.html) (formerly Kayser-Threde GmbH). PK-4 is funded by ESA and Roscosmos. Additional funding for the project in Germany was provided by the [The Ger­man Space Agen­cy at DLR](http://www.dlr.de/rd/en/desktopdefault.aspx) and the [Max Planck So­ci­ety](http://www.mpg.de/en).

Comment: Dusty plasma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dusty_plasma

Comment: @A.Rumlin https://twitter.com/novitskiy_iss/status/1413531482862366720 and https://twitter.com/novitskiy_iss/status/1413531494342086671

Comment: So the wikipedia link is the answer.

Comment: @A.Rumlin I don't think so. "...what has been learned from making plasma crystals in space?" is not answered by that article. I have a very strong hunch that there will be some good review articles and popular articles about the work on the ISS, and a short summary of those (with links) would be *great!*

Comment: The video about the experiment describes in more detail, but there are no English subtitles there.

Comment: @A.Rumlin Thanks for your answer! In this case I think it's fine, the visuals are already helpful and informative. I think there is also an easy way to download the subtitles (closed captions) text file from the website. I'll look into that and let you know.

Comment: @A.Rumlin Oh it's easy! See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62411809)  and https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AY9v.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMMyH.png 00:00
[музыка]
00:09
известно что вещество может пребывать
00:12
4 фазовых состояниях твердом жидком и
00:15
газообразном и плазме
00:17
плазма это 99,9 процентов массой
00:21
видимого вещества вселенной начиная от
00:23
звезд и заканчивая межзвёздным газом
00:25
земле плазма это молнии северное сияние
00:28
или например газоразрядные лампы плазма
00:31...

Comment: @A.Rumlin there's also a python package to download it https://stackoverflow.com/a/57320152/3904031

Comment: Or you can use a site like downsub.com The main problem with such auto-generated subtitles is incorrect recognition of words in the audio track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2019: https://www.roscosmos.ru/26185/

> Исследования, проводимые космонавтами на борту Международной космической станции, меняют взгляд на процессы, которые моделируют на Земле. Олег Кононенко начал работать над российско-германским экспериментом «Плазменный кристалл», исследующим четвертое состояние вещества — плазму.

Research carried out by astronauts aboard the International Space Station is changing the way things are simulated on Earth. Oleg Kononenko began working on the Russian-German experiment "Plasma Crystal", which investigates the fourth state of matter - plasma.

> После его подробного изучения в космосе выяснилось, что плазма имеет кристаллическую решетку. Это полностью перевернуло представление ученых о том, что такое четвертое состояние вещества. На МКС эксперимент похож на земной, но только в специальной камере применяется настоящий вакуум. Для последующей обработки результатов используются мощные компьютеры.

After a detailed study of it in space, it turned out that plasma has a crystal lattice. This completely turned the idea of scientists about what the fourth state of matter is. On the ISS, the experiment is similar to Earth's, but only in a special chamber a real vacuum is applied. For the subsequent processing of the results, powerful computers are used.

> Суть эксперимента заключается в том, что в камере создается плазма, а в плазменную среду вводятся маленькие пылевые частицы. Наблюдать их поведение можно только в невесомости, поскольку на Земле гравитация сдавливает кристаллы, а значит и нельзя понять поведение плазмы. В космосе же кристаллы «взлетают», образуя объемную трехмерную структуру.

The essence of the experiment is that a plasma is created in the chamber, and small dust particles are introduced into the plasma medium. Their behavior can only be observed in zero gravity, since on Earth gravity squeezes the crystals, which means that it is impossible to understand the behavior of plasma. In space, crystals "take off", forming a three-dimensional structure.

> Полученные «завихрения» повторяют строение Галактики Млечный Путь, и только здесь можно узнать, как она зарождалась. Для генетиков этот эксперимент тоже стал открытием: если плазму охлаждать, то получается копия строения молекулы ДНК. Еще одно направление — борьба с бактериями, невосприимчивыми к земным лекарствам.

The resulting "swirls" repeat the structure of the Milky Way Galaxy, and only here you can find out how it originated. For geneticists, this experiment also became a discovery: if the plasma is cooled, then a copy of the structure of the DNA molecule is obtained. Another area is the fight against bacteria that are immune to earthly drugs.

---

2021: https://www.roscosmos.ru/30359/

> **Ожидаемые результаты:**
> Условия микрогравитации позволяют исследовать процессы взаимодействия частиц микронных размеров в плазме, образования плазменно-пылевых кристаллов без искажения силой тяжести, что недостижимо в земных условиях.

**Expected results:**
Microgravity conditions make it possible to study the processes of interaction of micron-sized particles in plasma, the formation of plasma-dust crystals without being distorted by gravity, which is unattainable in terrestrial conditions.

> Результаты эксперимента дадут новые знания для следующих возможных практических приложений:
>
> - создание покрытий при контролируемом осаждении взвешенных в плазме
> - частиц на подложку; удаление пылевых частиц при плазменном травлении;
> - сепарация пылевых частиц по размерам .

The results of the experiment will provide new knowledge for the following possible practical applications:

- creation of coatings with controlled deposition of suspended in plasma
- particles on the substrate; removal of dust particles during plasma etching;
- separation of dust particles by size.

> **Полученные результаты:**
>
> Исследования, проведенные на аппаратуре «Плазменный кристалл-3», позволили обнаружить ряд совершенно новых эффектов в плазме с сильно заряженными макрочастицами:
>
> - впервые обнаружено формирование трехмерных упорядоченных структур сильнозаряженных частиц микронного размера с большим параметром неидеальности (трехмерный плазменный кристалл) с гранецентрированной и объемно-центрированной решетками;
> - открыто одновременное сосуществование гранецентрированных и гексагональных структур;
> - осуществлено возбуждение волн пылевой компоненты, что дает возможность получения дисперсионных соотношений и исследования характера волн;
>   обнаружены нелинейные волны плотности пылевой компоненты;
> - обнаружено существование областей с конвективным движением заряженных макрочастиц в плазменной жидкости («плазменно-пылевые вихри»), поведение частиц в которых существенно отличается от наблюдаемых в условиях гравитации.
> - продемонстрирована возможность исследования роста микрочастиц в условиях микрогравитации.

The results obtained:
Investigations carried out on the Plasma Crystal-3 equipment revealed a number of completely new effects in plasma with highly charged macroparticles:

- for the first time, the formation of three-dimensional ordered structures of highly charged micron-sized particles with a large nonideality parameter (three-dimensional plasma crystal) with face-centered and body-centered lattices was discovered;
- the simultaneous coexistence of face-centered and hexagonal structures is discovered;
- the excitation of the dust component waves has been carried out, which makes it possible to obtain dispersion relations and study the nature of the waves;
  discovered nonlinear density waves of the dust component;
- the existence of regions with convective motion of charged macroparticles in a plasma liquid ("plasma-dust vortices") was discovered, the behavior of particles in which differs significantly from that observed under gravitational conditions.
- the possibility of studying the growth of microparticles under microgravity conditions has been demonstrated.